# Finding the age of change sets in a merge

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to find the time it takes from checking in a change to a branch to that changeset getting merged up to a parent branch. I've been playing with the TFS API and have tried to use the GetBranchHistory and QueryMergesExtended methods but they don't seem to return anything in a reasonable time frame.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this information?

Thanks

Comment: "I'm trying to find the time it takes from checking in a change to a branch to that changeset getting merged up to a parent branch." You mean how much time the developer takes to o that?

Comment: No not really. I have development teams that work in separate branches. At the moment we only merge up to our main line when we release the software. I'm trying to show how long we take to release software, given that it is ready to be released.

Comment: Do you want to automate it or seeing it in source control explorer is fine?

Comment: I want to automate it, I'm trying to build a web dashboard showing waste and hopefully how we are reducing this over time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the TrackChangesets method for that. I haven't tried myself but looks like this is what you are looking for.

Looks like the return type VersionControlBranchVisualizer has what you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.versioncontrolbranchvisualizerext.trackchangesets.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For tfs2010 you can use VersionControlServer.TrackMerges for get IEnumerable<ExtendedMerge>. See example [here](https://tfsmerge.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TfsMerge/Service/Tfs.cs) (method TrackMerges).